# two js function loading in one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i made a simple website where i have 2 function that loads my pages in menu in one page the problem is when i load one it works ok but when i click on the other same page is load is it not possible to use this kind of function?this is the code

```
$('#firstcontent1').click(function(){
            $('#content1').load('pages/firstcontent1.php');
        });
$('#firstcontent2').click(function(){
            $('#content1').load('pages/firstcontent2.php');
        });
$('#firstcontent3').click(function(){
            $('#content1').load('pages/firstcontent3.php');
        });
```

this the HTML

```
<div id="content1">

    </div>
    <div >
            <ul id="menu-list">
                <li id="firstcontent1"><a href="#">firstcontent1</a>
                </li>
                <li id="firstcontent2"><a href="#">firstcontent2</a>
                </li>
                <li id="firstcontent3"><a href="#">firstcontent3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

the other is

```
$('#secondcontent1').click(function(){
            $('#content2').load('page/secondcontent1.php');
        });
$('#secondcontent2').click(function(){
            $('#content2').load('page/secondcontent2.php');
        });
$('#secondcontent3').click(function(){
            $('#content2').load('page/secondcontent3.php');
        });
```

this is the HTML

```
<div >
            <ul id="menu-list">
                <li id="secondcontent1"><a href="#">secondcontent1</a>
                </li>
                <li id="secondcontent2"><a href="#">secondcontent2</a>
                </li>
                <li id="secondcontent3"><a href="#">secondcontent3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content2" >

        </div>
```

as you can see the id are different and the page name are different as well as the container but for example i load/click id of pages1, content1 will load pages1 and content2 will load page1 as well..i thought when i click on id pages1 content1 will load pages1 but content2 will not load page1 because i did not click the id of page1.

**UPDATE:**

i notice this only content1 is loaded in content2 for example when i click id pages1 content1 and content2 will load pages1 but when i click pages2 only content2 will load and content1 stays the same meaning the correct page

Comment: What does the console say ?

Comment: console has no error its just that they both load when only 1 should load

Comment: @Sedz why would the console say anything? This isn't a coding error, but a misunderstanding of how the code works by the coder.

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII you might be right , BUT there might be a syntax or other error stoping this from working. 
I was writing a comment asking for more code; :) Because after his comment I felt like I am lost with the question 
Thanks for your comment

Comment: @Sedz nothing is shown in the console..by the way i notice this only content1 is loaded in content2 for example when i click id pages1 content1 and content2 will load pages1 but when i click pages2 only content2 will load and content1 stays the same meaning the correct page

Comment: @HakHak can you please add more code OR post the code to jsfiddle.net and post the link

Comment: @HakHak your code WORKS. Please post some HTML sample... I'd really say you have some typo in there...

Comment: is the second menu loaded after clicking on the first menu ?

Comment: no they are quicklink one is on the right the other is on the left they are in different pages as well i am registering in fiddle this will be two separate fiddle because they are two different page

Comment: OK please post the link when you are done by updating your question

Comment: @Sedz how can i put the page to be load because it is in a different folder all of the pages to be loaded

Comment: Forget about that but a dummy data in it , and please try putting alert("test"); instead of load in your code at your machine

Comment: @Sedz sorry for late notice but i cant duplicated the effect in fiddle it very different

Comment: Can you give an example of the code that is being loaded from the server?

Comment: Second Content has `page` in the url versus `pages`. Also, you sure your relative path's are working ?

Comment: @Ani it is not a typo sir i separated it because the got confuse with the pages but still when i click link1 container1 loads page1 but container2 loads page1 what i want is only when i click link1 container1 loads page1forcontainer1 when i click link1 on container2 page1forcontainer2 will load

Comment: @HakHak - [If I copy your code it works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/cJKCy/) (I only replaced `.load(...)` with `.html(...)` for demo purposes). I think you're going to have to provide more information before anyone can help. I believe I understand the problem you're facing (when you click `firstcontent1` it is loaded in both `content1` and `content2`?). The only problem is that that doesn't happen with the code you posted, so there is going to have to be some other factor somewhere which causes the behaviour you're seeing. Therefore, can you explain more or provide more code? Which browser?

Comment: ids must be unique, you have two ul's with the id of "menu-list" => `<ul id="menu-list">`

Comment: @AminJafari i already tried naming them separately but still same result..i rename all differently even separated the pages to load to avoid confusion but still same...

Comment: I know it sounds silly but have you checked the content of "pages/firstcontent1.php" and "page/secondcontent1.php"? maybe the contents are the same! :-s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your issue might be coming from a typo. You are trying to load the path `page/content` and `pages/content`. Not sure if that is just a paste error, but figured I would point that out. Also, **it is probably not working because you are using the same `id` twice** -- `menu-list`. Instead, use a class.

In any event, instead of having 6 different functions, you can consolidate all of this into 1 and then now you can narrow down the issue, if there still is one.

There is also no need to have an `<a>` tags if you aren't linking it to anything. Instead you are using the jQuery event handlers to capture that click.

This could be the HTML format :

```
<div id="content1"></div>
<div>
    <ul class="menu-list" data="content1">
        <li id="firstcontent1">firstcontent1</li>
            .
            .
            .
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="content2"></div>
<div>
    <ul class="menu-list" data="content2">
        <li id="secondcontent1">secondcontent1</li>
            .
            .
            .
    </ul>
</div>
```

Next, your consolidated jQuery should look like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu-list li').click(function(){
        var content = "#" + $(this).parent().data();
        var page = "pages/" + $(this).attr('id') + ".php";

        $(content).load(page);
    });
});
```

If you are using jQuery POST version 1.7 your function should like like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu-list li', function(){
    var content = "#" + $(this).parent().data();
    var page = "pages/" + $(this).attr('id') + ".php";

    $(content).load(page);
});
```

Now you have yourself a universal function for menu-lists, all you need to do is follow the HTML syntax. As a general programming rule, if you are repeating yourself a lot, chances are you are doing something wrong, or could be doing something better.

EDIT ::

Your issue could be coming from trying to load a page before the last one has completely finished loading.

What happens when you try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.menu-list li').click(function(){
        var content = "#" + $(this).parent().data();
        var page = "pages/" + $(this).attr('id') + ".php";

        $(content).load(function(){
            $(this).load(page);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: actually i really did separate all the pages it is not a typo error... my problem is that why does the other container load the pages that is to be loaded on the other pages...sir do you get what my problem is or do i need to further explain it?

Comment: @HakHak you could be referencing the wrong folders. Have you tried switching them? Another reason could be because of duplicate `id`'s

Comment: sir i think the folder is ok but im not sure about the code maybe the js has something to do with how they behave..im still trying to figure out what causes this behavior..i will try putting them into one folder maybe it will change something

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:  [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qcALK/1/)
Same as your code. this works.

You have a typo as I mentioned in the comment. You code is fine otherwise, works.

**Typo**:

`page` vs `pages`. Also, make sure your relative path's are working for both pages.

Comment: sir it does work both of them my problem is il give an example...for example i click the link1 in container1 to load pages/page1 container2 also loads pages/page what i want is container2 link1 will populate that container...page in pages should populate the container1 and page in page should populate container2 should i further explain myself?

Answer (score 0):

are pages1 and page1 nested, if so the event handle will bubble through both events. Can you try setting 
`$('#page1').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
            $('#content2').load('page/page1.php');
        });`

Comment: yes :) the event.preventDefault will stop the event from bubbling up to other event handler. This ensure that only the inner most event handler is run.

Comment: this is pure guessing, but yes could be a possible problem if you have a button inside another button which sounds like quite a strange architecture to me...

Comment: did i say the they are in different div and different page?when i click the id of pages1 content2 still loads pages1 and cotent1 too

Answer (score 0):

Try to use live bind:

```
$('#menu-list').on('click', '#firstcontent1', function(){
    $('#content1').load('pages/firstcontent1.php');
});
```

Tell us what it happened next. =D

Answer (score 0):

Try changing all these:

```
$('#secondcontent1').click(function(){
        $('#content2').load('page/secondcontent1.php');
});
```

To something like this:

```
$('#secondcontent1').click(function(event){
         event.stopPropagation();
        $('#content2').load('page/secondcontent1.php');
});
```

Add the event.stopPropagation() to each click event and remember to change the function() to function(event).

Comment: i did try your  code sir but unfortunately i still get the same result sa the previous code

Answer (score 0):

I think do you want code like this

```
<div id="content1">

</div>
<div >
    <ul class="menu-list">
       <li id="firstcontent1"><a href="#">firstcontent1</a>
       </li>
        <li id="firstcontent2"><a href="#">firstcontent2</a>
        </li>
        <li id="firstcontent3"><a href="#">firstcontent3</a>
        </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div >
        <ul class="menu-list">
            <li id="secondcontent1"><a href="#">secondcontent1</a>
            </li>
            <li id="secondcontent2"><a href="#">secondcontent2</a>
            </li>
            <li id="secondcontent3"><a href="#">secondcontent3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Then you want the script like this

```
$('.menu-list li').unbind('click').click(function(){
  var id=$(this).attr('id');
  var page='pages/'+id+'.php';
  $('#content1').load(page);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a cache issue.

Try to use JQuery .ajax, and set no caching for each request:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"pages/firstcontent1.php",success:function(result){
    $("#content1").html(result);
    },
    cache: false
});
```

In order to see if it's a caching issue / multiple requests per click - run [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and see the exact requests that are being sent - on click.

1. if you see more than 1 request per click - it means that you're creating multiple requests, instead of a single request - need to fix via "[Delegate](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)" & "[event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)"
2. if you see 1 request per click - click again, and see if the response state in Fiddler is 304 OR you don't see the second request at all - if that's the case - use the solution above; or you can gain no-caching with ".load" via

   ```
   $.ajaxSetup ({
       cache: false
   });
   ```

Comment: can you complete your answer and provide explanation